# Cycles baking not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normal-map

I am learning how to bake textures in Blender and I made a simple high poly mesh by subdividing a plane couple of times and poked the faces out.

[image]

I then added a plane, did no changes to it, and added a material to it, and also added an *Image Texture* node in the *Shader Editor*, and created and assigned a new image there with default properties, and selected that image node.

Now I changed my render engine to *Cycles*, selected the high poly mesh, then while holding *Shift* I also selected the low poly mesh. I expanded the *Bake* dropdown, and set the *Bake Type* to *Normal*, checked *Selected to Active*, set the *Extrusion* to about *0.1 m*, and that's it. I then clicked *Bake*.
It takes much less time in Texture Baking than I anticipated, and just gives me a plane blue image.

[image]

I believe no other baking types are working.

[Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtRvrsqSyyL2gXsykNY9tiluVUS7?e=cAQYtd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the plane above the object. The ray will go in the opposite direction of the plane normal, if it doesn't hit any surface, it won't bake anything:

[image]

Comment: One more thing- If it scans opposite of its normal (that it does), then why does the baking work when you place the low poly mesh at the same position as the high poly?

Comment: Because you've given an Extrusion of 0.1, which will make the ray begin a bit above the surface, if you choose 0, the ray will begin at the face surface and won't hit the high-poly surfaces